# Запуск Task'a с определенным периодом

Tags: c#, task

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы Task выполнял функцию раз в минуту. Если да, то как. Понятно, что есть другие , возможно, более удобные или более подходящие для этого средства, как тот же таймер, но все же интересно

Comment: Извращение в виде Task.Run() и Task.Delay() с коррекцией периода по времени

Comment: @vitidev понятно, спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы хотите это:

```
async Task RepeatEvery(TimeSpan ts, Action action)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var wait = Task.Delay(ts);
        action();
        await wait;
    }
}
```

Если `action` — «длинная» функция, возможно, её стоит выгрузить в пул потоков через `await Task.Run(action)`.

Comment: Спасибо, работает как надо

Comment: @MikhailZnak: Пожалуйста!